# Como passar multiplas lista em um query? Usando JPQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

O problema é o seguinte: Tenho um controller que recebe uma lista de Integers: `[1245,12346 ...]`

Na minha tabela preciso consultar usando essa lista mas as colunas estão separadas, ou seja, os primeiros digitos estão em uma coluna e os ultimos em outra.

Pensei em fazer algo do tipo:

```
@Query("SELECT ep FROM EP ep WHERE ep.numero1 = :numero1 AND ep.numero2 = :numero2 ")
    public EP findByNumeros(@Param("numero1") List<Integer> numero1,
            @Param("numero2") List<Integer> numero2);
```

O problema: Ao passar uma lista com 3 valores, ele acaba interando 6 vezes. Exemplo: Se eu passar uma lista [0,1,2] e outra [0,1,2] ele faz a seguinte consulta: 0,1 - 0,2 - 0,3 - 1,0 - 1,1 ... e assim por diante.

Eu gostaria que ele fizesse somente: 0,0, - 1,1 - 2,2.

Alguém saber como resolver isso? Já tentei o seguinte:

```
@Query("SELECT ep FROM EP ep WHERE (ep.numero1, ep.numero2) IN ((:numero1), (:numero2))")
    public List<EP> findByNumeros(@Param("numero1") List<Integer> numero1,
            @Param("numero2") List<Integer> numero2);
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 920, SQLState: 42000
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Answer (score 0):

Se são duas listas diferentes para diferentes campos na tabela, use o `IN` separadamente:

```
@Query("SELECT ep FROM EP ep WHERE ep.numero1 in (:numero1) and ep.numero2 in(:numero2)")
```